# Blender 2.8 - show hidden files in file browser?

Tags: workflow, file-format, file-browser

I'm working on Blender installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I installed my fonts using the Typecatcher in order to get Google Web Fonts. Typecatcher installs the fonts in a user home directory under `~/.fonts/typecatcher/`.

Unfortunately I can not 'Unhide' the hidden directory in Blender in order to get access to the fonts (the one with the dot in front). I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> but that doesn't work. Is there a way to get access to that location or should I just move the fonts to another location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can click the *Filter* dropdown menu (*Display Mode*) at the top-right of the *File Browser* in order to enable 'Show Hidden' which displays *all files* (or just press <kbd>H</kbd> to toggle the that mode on/off):

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Andreli